# ASP.NET MVC Controllers/Views invoked

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, view, controller

When I invoke a controller, it's possible that the view response calls other controllers.  Is there a way to determine, in MVC, all of the views and/or controllers were called in a single response?

Thanks.

Comment: We have controllers, which have Actions. We have Actions which returns views of some sort. And we have views that are the markup for your page. A controller doesnt call a view, a controller's action renders the view. Can you refine your question a bit more to give us an understand of what you're trying to do? Maybe with a quick example of what you want to detect (like Controler A, Action B calls Action C and returns View C which also has View F)

Comment: Html.Action can call a controller and serves up a view, which is what I was meaning.  Essentially, I want to grab the names of the controllers and of the views that executed when I navigate to /Home/Index.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think that the framework exposes this directly, but you could hook into the OnActionExecuted method and log each action that gets invoked along with a unique request identifier. You could hook into Application_BeginRequest in global.asax.cs to generate a GUID to use as the unique id for that request (stored in the Session, but overwritten for each new request).  If you use a base controller and derive all your controllers from it, you could put the logging in the base controllers OnActionExecuted method to keep it DRY.

Alternatively, you could look at creating a custom ActionInvoker and put the logging there.

This is where I would start anyway, though, there might be a better way.

NOTE: This will only tie together actions that are invoked **server-side** for the request.  Any AJAX requests kicked off client-side when client receives the rendered view will show up as different requests.  If you need to include those as well, your unique id generation code should probably only run on non-AJAX requests, leaving the existing id alone in the session otherwise.  Typically AJAX requests have an `HTTP_X_Requested_With` header to distinguish them.

Comment: Thanks, i'll look into it.  I expected the AJAX problem.  I'm OK with only the ones that are called from the server.